# How to get result of comparison three value in Codeigniter

Tags: javascript

I want ask about Javascript and Codeigniter.

I want get the result from comparison of three integer value. I've try but the result just show one result and the result pass only. Even though I'm set two result pass and fail.

Here the code: [Edit: what I have a tried so far]

```
function sum_method(){
    var result = document.querySelector('[name="result"]')[0].value;
    var value_from = document.querySelector('[name="value_from"]').value;
    var value_to = document.querySelector('[name="value_to"]').value;

    var result1 = parseInt(value_from) >= parseInt(result);
    var result2 = parseInt(value_to) <= parseInt(result);
    
    if ((result1) == true && (result2) == true)
    {
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'pass';
    }else{
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'fail';
    }
}
```

[image: the field result will comparison with requirement value from and value to and the status will show what result from the comparison pass or fail]

The field test result will comparison with requirement value from and value to and the status will show what result from the comparison pass or fail.

Can you all show me the good code?

[image: the picture has been success to show the status, but in the new row the status cannot seen]

the picture has been success to show the status, but in the new row the status cannot seen

Comment: If you want single element then would have to use `querySelector` instead of `querySelectorAll`. Also you don't need to check if `isNaN` since you are already using `parseInt`

Comment: Hi @Adi Thank you for response my question. I've already try your suggest but still get the same output.

Comment: Can you please add what have you tried so far as well then?

Comment: oh don't add it to the comments, just update your post, with a section saying `Edit: what i have a tried so far`

Comment: I've already edit the code @Adi

Comment: you have a typo for function declaration. Also did you try it with `document.getElementById`?

Comment: Yes, I also tried `document.getElementById`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255857/discussion-between-ayu-asri-lestari-and-adi).

Comment: Please don't keep re-tagging this with Codeigniter - it has nothing to do with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few problems in the code:

1. `document.querySelector('[name="result"]')[0].value;` is a syntax error.
   [`querySelector` returns a single element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), not an array, so this line throws an error, and your `result` variable is never set.  You would see this error if you check [your browser's devtools console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/Tools_and_setup/What_are_browser_developer_tools).
2. It isn't clear from the text of your question exactly what the test is supposed to check, but based on the names of your `input`s, I think the `result` value should be between the `value_from` and `value_to` values to pass?  Eg with from=1 and to=10, any result between 1 and 10 should pass?

   If so, you simply have your tests backwards:

   ```
   var result1 = parseInt(value_from) >= parseInt(result);
   var result2 = parseInt(value_to) <= parseInt(result);
   ```

   The `value_from` value is the *bottom* of the range of acceptable values, so `result` must be *greater* than it for a pass - here you check if it is less than.  And `value_to` is the *top* of the range, so `result` must be *less* than that to pass, not greater than, as you check here.

   If you're having trouble with the logic, add some `console.log()`s to check the numbers.

Fixing those 2 problems is enough to get your code working, run the snippet below to see.  Type a number in any input field to test.

```js
// Run the check every time a key is pressed in an input
let allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
allInputs.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      sum_method();
    });
});

// Run the check
function sum_method() {
    // console.log('sum_method');
    var result = document.querySelector('[name="result"]').value;
    var value_from = document.querySelector('[name="value_from"]').value;
    var value_to = document.querySelector('[name="value_to"]').value;

    // console.log('result:', result, 'value_from:', value_from, 'value_to:', value_to);
  
    var result1 = parseInt(value_from) <= parseInt(result);
    var result2 = parseInt(value_to) >= parseInt(result);
    
    // console.log('result1', result1, 'result2', result2);

    if (result1 == true && result2 == true) {
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'pass';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'fail';
    }
}
```

```html
From: <input type="text" name="value_from" value="1">
To: <input type="text" name="value_to" value="10">

<p>Test Result: <input type="text" name="result"></p>

<p>Status: <input type="text" name="status" readonly></p>
```

#### Suggestion

IMO it is not surprising you got the tests mixed up, as the code is more complicated and confusing than it has to be.  If you need to check a value is between 2 other values, a test like this is much easier to read, understand, and get right when you're writing it:

```
if (lower <= value && value <= higher) {
```

Simplified snippet below.

```js
// Run the check every time a key is pressed in an input
let allInputs = document.querySelectorAll("input");
allInputs.forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
      sum_method();
    });
});

// Run the check
function sum_method() {
    var result = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="result"]').value);
    var value_from = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="value_from"]').value);
    var value_to = parseInt(document.querySelector('[name="value_to"]').value);

    if (value_from <= result && result <= value_to) {
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'pass';
    } else {
        document.querySelector('[name="status"]').value = 'fail';
    }
}
```

```html
From: <input type="text" name="value_from" value="1">
To: <input type="text" name="value_to" value="10">

<p>Test Result: <input type="text" name="result"></p>

<p>Status: <input type="text" name="status" readonly></p>
```

Comment: Hi thank you the answer can resolved the problem. But, if I add the new row the result isn't seen